# How do I make VBA auto-find multiple blocks of values in a column and emulate the autosum function?

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to come up with code that checks for groups of 2 or more rows with values in them and then sums the values in the cells in column "O" in each group. Currently, groups of 2 or more non-empty rows are separated from the next non-empty row below by two empty rows. I am using the following code with *some* success:

```
Sub AutoSum()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim LastRow As Integer
Dim FirstRowWithValue As Integer
'Search code
LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row

Dim i As Long
'Begin loop code
For i = LastRow + 1 To 3 Step -1

If IsEmpty(Range("I" & i)) And Range("I" & i) <> Range("I" & i).Offset(-1) Then

        If Range("I" & i).Offset(-1) = Range("I" & i).Offset(-2) Then
            Dim cell1 As String
            Dim cell2 As String
            cell1 = Range("O" & i).Offset(-1).End(xlUp).Address
            cell2 = Range("O" & i).Offset(-1).Address
            Range("O" & i).Value = "=sum(" & (cell1) & ":" & (cell2) & ")"
            i = FirstRowWithValue + 1
        End If

End If

Next i

Columns("O").AutoFit


Application.ScreenUpdating = True
'End loop code


Application.ScreenUpdating = True
'End loop code
End Sub
```

You'll notice it is checking column "I". That is because in each of the groups of rows, the values in column "I" will be the same. That is the criterion this code is using to determine the appropriate range of rows to sum.

The problem is that this code does not work if there is more than one group of 2 or more rows with values in them. It starts checking at the bottom, finds one, executes code in side the IF-THEN statement, and then does nothing to any groups above the first. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible issue i see with your code is that your `FirstRowWithValue` variable is not being initialized to any value. Since you haven't set it to any value, it will automatically be set to 0, and will set i to 1, ending your loop and your macro. You either need to set this value on your own, or delete that line of code.

```
'Sets i to 1, set FirstRowWithValue or Delete this line
i = FirstRowWithValue + 1
```

Comment: Wow, I sure feel stupid. I have been wracking my brain trying to understand why this was not working, and it was because of that line, which was left over from an earlier version of the code. I forgot to take it out and didn't even notice it was still there. I also took out the second, unnecessary `Application.ScreenUpdating = True`. Thank you!